# Set custom error message for camel json-validator component

Tags: apache-camel, json-schema-validator

I need to set the custom error messages upon the `camel JSON-validator` component if any field fails for the mentioned property.
Currently, I'm getting default error message `"org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.JsonValidationException: JSon validation error with 1 errors."`
Below is the `JSON` schema added in the code.

```
Camel context.xml code

<camelContext  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route  streamCache="true">
<from id="_from1" uri="restlet:http://0.0.0.0:9902/validateData?restletMethod=POST"/>
<to uri="json-validator:validateData.json"/>
</route>
</camelContext>

validateData.json

{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {

    },
    "type": "object",
    "title": "The Root Schema",
    "required": [
        "MobileNumber"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "MobileNumber": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The MobileNumber Schema",
            "minLength": 10,
            "maxLength": 10,
            "default": "",
            "pattern": "^(.*)$",
            "messages": {
                "MobileNumber": "MobileNumber not valid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Any suggestions please?**

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a good solution for yours?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two options:

Option 1: Provide your own ErrorHandler implementation

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/json-validator-component.html

> errorHandler (advanced) | To use a custom ValidatorErrorHandler. The default error handler captures the errors and throws an exception. | JsonValidatorErrorHandler

Option 2: Extract the error messages from the exception

```java
final ValidationException ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, ValidationException.class);

if (ex instanceof JsonValidationException) {
    Set<ValidationMessage> errors = ((JsonValidationException)ex).getErrors();
    for (ValidationMessage e : errors) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use the [error handling of Camel](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/error-handling-in-camel.html), for example an [Exception clause](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html) for the specific Exception you want to customize:

```
<onException>
    <exception>org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.JsonValidationException</exception>
    <throwException exceptionType="com.your.app.CustomException" message="Your much better exception message"/>
</onException>
```

Or you can handle the problem locally by using [Camels try/catch variant](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/try-catch-finally.html):

```
<doTry>
    <to uri="json-validator:validateData.json"/>
    <doCatch>
        <exception>org.apache.camel.component.jsonvalidator.JsonValidationException</exception>
        <setHeader name="jsonValidationFailed">
            <constant>true</constant>
        </setHeader>
    </doCatch>
</doTry>
```

Important to say: **The try/catch block disables Camels error handling**. I remember that it has no effect to throw a custom exception in this block (but you can try it, I am not sure about this). Therefore you could set a message header as a "marker" and check this later in the route to throw the custom exception.